# Send BackColor value to another form

Tags: c#, colors, send, backcolor

I have a Form1 and a Form2. Form2 is a "Options" Form.
With a button on Form1, I open the Form2.

On Form2 i have radioButtons. The RadioButtons are changing the Color of a panel (e.g panel1). This BackColor should be send to Form1 panel1.

How can I do this?

I tried it with the other Topics, but they are only about TextBoxes and not about BackColor of Panels.

Comment: The Topic which the one I have supposed to duplicate (why?) is only about TextBoxes. I tried this to change for using for BackColor, but i didn't worked.

Comment: The duplicate shows how to send values (such as numbers, text, or colors) to another form. If you couldn't get it to work, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30282200/edit) your question to show us what you tried and explain why you think it didn't work.